# How to populate a mysql table with data from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with a many-to-many relation, and a joint table between them, for example:

```
client (id, name)
address (id, address)
client_address (client_id, address_id)
```

I need to populate the client_address table with a line for every client, using a specific address, like:

```
client_id, address_id
1,         1
2,         1
3,         1
4,         1
etc...
```

I tried something like this (which obviously does not work):

```
INSERT INTO 
  client_address (`client_id`, `address_id`) 
  SELECT id from client, 
  SELECT id from address where address = 'My Address';
```

can I do this with a single query?

Comment: How do you know which address a client has?

Comment: A client can have many addresses, but it needs to have a least one (the one whit the WHERE in the example).

Comment: Do you have any information in address table like client_id ? Or an information in client table like address_id ? Just to know how to JOIN these tables ?

Comment: no, thsi is a many to many relation.

Comment: Even if it is many to many relation, according to your schema there is no relation between the address table and the client table. How could we know that address x belongs to client y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to populate it manually just like your example you can try to use CROSS JOIN :

```
INSERT INTO 
  client_address (`client_id`, `address_id`) 
  SELECT c.id, a.id 
  FROM client c, 
  CROSS JOIN address a 
  WHERE address = 'My Address';
```

This will create a line for every client you have in CLIENT table and the address you chose in the WHERE clause